# comment node with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: dom, html-agility-pack

I want to hide a node with specific image from display. If I basically set style="display:none" a vast majority of browsers continues to download image in that node with wrong src :(

So I decided make this node commented in html and uncomment it when I need that image to show.

Could not find an obvious trick to do this with HtmlAgility. Could you please give me a right way to solve it?

Comment: I don't know that HtmlAgility, but it is simple to add an image with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure this should be done at the server-side? If not use javascript.

Comment: It should be on the server side. To solve this issue I decided now simply to add small 1x1 px placeholder image on that cases. So this question now is mostly theoretical.

Comment: It would be easier to rename the `<img>` tag e.g. to `<temp-img>` and vice versa then.

Comment: @Alex are there any consequences with renaming <img> to hide? Example would this be bad practice as it could throw errors in different situations?